# How to remove duplicate entries from database?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table "tweets"

```
tweet_id  call_id   id_str  timestamp  text
--------------------------------------------------
1         11        12345   312323134  lorem ipsum
2         11        12345   312323134  lorem ipsum
3         11        12345   312323134  lorem ipsum
4         11        12345   312323134  lorem ipsum
5         11        67890   325565454  dolor
6         11        34355   333544664  samet
```

Each tweet should only appear once in the database. As you can see, the exact same tweet (same  call_id, id_str, timestamp and text - on other words everything is the same except for the tweet_id (which is an autonumbering field)) has been stored 4 times (!)

Is there a way to exact matches (so: same everything except tweet_id) and then delete the last x - 1 (here: 4  -1 = 3) of them? In other words, the cleaned-up table would look like

```
tweet_id  call_id   id_str  timestamp  text
--------------------------------------------------
1         11        12345   312323134  lorem ipsum
5         11        67890   325565454  dolor
6         11        34355   333544664  samet
```

I hope there's an easy way to do this, because otherwise I have a huge problem (shows you what putting in an extra hour of thinking before you actually build your database can do!)

Comment: This question must have been answered a million times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you searched for a solution online before asking this question ???? if not here is an online tutorial on how to do this.

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/deleting-duplicate-records

Comment: Thanks for that. (i) I have copied the tweets table into tweets_new (ii) In tweets_new, I dropped the tweet_id column (iii) I created a table called tweets_distinct with the same structure as tweets_new (iv) Following the tutorial, I though this should do the trick: `SELECT DISTINCT * INTO tweets_distinct FROM tweets_new` - however, I get an error: `#1327 - Undeclared variable: tweets_distinct`. I don't understand since I double and triple checked but the tweets_distinct table really exists (no spelling mistakes or something). Your thoughts please :-)

Comment: P.S. I could easily delete the tweet_id column since it hasn't yet been referenced anywhere. So I can first create a cleaned up table and afterwards insert an auto_increment field for numbering the tweets again.

Comment: That statement probably does not work in mysql, but in other rdbms. You can use `insert into tweets_new select * from tweets_distinct`, or even better, specify column names: `insert into tweets_new(a,b) select a,b from tweets_distinct`

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would be to copy the cleansed data in a new table, drop the old, put the cleansed back in the old.

to get the unique entries, you can easily do:

```
select max(tweet_id) as tweet_id,  call_id,   id_str,  timestamp,  text from tbl group by  call_id,   id_str,  timestamp,  text
```